# Dockerized Tensorflow script can't see GPUs

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, tensorflow2.0

I use docker containers to train deep learning models. These Docker containers are located on a Linux server and are trained there with several GPUs.

The problem is that Tensorflow does not recognize the GPUs inside the container. The Docker container looks like this:

```py
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    pkg-config \
    python3-pip \
    python3.6 \
    nano \ 
    wget \
    yasm


FROM python:3.6
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Here tensorflow-gpu == 2.1 is installed
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./main.py"]
```

If you now comment out the python specific lines from the docker file and replace them with CMD["nvidia-smi"] you can see that the GPUs inside the container are visible. Now the only question I have to ask myself is how it is possible for Tensorflow to detect the GPUs.

In Python code the GPUs are included as follows:

```py
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    for physical_device in physical_devices:
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_device, True)
```

Comment: Have you looked through https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Yes I have bevor I posted the question here. Unfortunately I did not find a working solution.

Comment: Couple more quick questions. Is there a reason you aren't using `tensorflows` docker images? Also what command are you using to run the container.

Comment: Because I've been instructed to include the cuda version. If there is another way to include Tensorflow 2.1 in the docker file it would be a natural option but I don't know how to do that.

Run command: docker run --gpus= all image_name [-flags ...]

Comment: Without have a good way to test it, all I can do is point your to other resources. This is the last one I think may help you, as it uses both `cuda` and tensorflows docker images https://medium.com/@RouYunPan/how-to-use-tensorflow-gpu-with-docker-2b72f784fdf3

Comment: Thank you very much I will be read into it and hope that maybe some comments will be added.